# How to determine a point lies on a polygon?

Tags: java, awt, polygon, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I was solving a question which requires to find out if a point lies strictly inside a Polygon or not

Well I'm aware of java awt package so I could use this

> polygon.contains(pointToCheck)

But the problem is according to the official documentation the [definition of insideness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness) is given as

> A point is considered to lie inside a Shape if and only if:
>
> - it lies completely inside theShape boundary or
> - it lies exactly on the Shape boundary and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing X direction is entirely inside the boundary or
> - it lies exactly on a horizontal boundary segment and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing Y direction is inside the boundary

So how do I remove the count of points that lie on the Polygon?

If anyone could suggest a better algorithm to check if a point lies strictly inside the polygon it would also be helpful.

Comment: Before addressing this problem, I suggest that you ponder two questions. 1) Are there really point on the boundary in your data set(s). 2) Assuming yes, does it really matter if they are sometimes misclassified as outside rather than on ?

Comment: Yes actually there are many points that lie on the polygon i have to eliminate those points and return the count of points that lie strictly inside it.

Comment: Could you explain why ? ("On a polygon" is a tricky concept.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hao algorithm for point-in-polygon includes checking if the point lies on the boundary. The [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328261365_Optimal_Reliable_Point-in-Polygon_Test_and_Differential_Coding_Boolean_Operations_on_Polygons) includes fairly understand psuedo-code if you want to write it yourself. I have written a javascript implementation [here](https://github.com/rowanwins/point-in-polygon-hao).

In the java world another option might be to look at the [Java Topological Suite](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). The [PointLocator method](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/PointLocator.html) probably does what you want.